# Does time.Sleep() block the context?

Tags: go, goroutine

[Documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Sleep) mentions that, *Sleep pauses the current goroutine(`G`) for at least the duration d*.

`G` cannot be in run-queue(grey circles below) for duration `d`.

### [image]

https://morsmachine.dk/go-scheduler

---

`P` is context. `M` is kernel thread

Assume there are 8 kernel threads(because 8 core CPU - `runtime.NumCPU()`)

Go runtime maintaining `runtime.GOMAXPROCS(runtime.NumCPU())` number of contexts.

---

Using GO version 1.12

1) In which queue does Goroutine(`G`) wait for duration `d`? I see run-queue(above in grey)

2) In that duration `d`, Does that corresponding context(`P`) schedule another Goroutine from its run-queue on that same kernel thread(`M`)?

3) Can GO program schedule a Goroutine on specific context(`P`) run-queue?

Comment: 0) why is this significant? These are low-level implementation details, subject to change between versions and target OS/arch. 1) the run queue is the queue. 2) Yes, scheduling another goroutine is the point of calling `Sleep`. 3) No, the program does not get control over low-level scheduling details, and should not care.